# How to assign integers to objects in a list?

Tags: c#, winforms

So I've got objects in a list, and I'm trying to assign an angle to each to travel at. Currently I've got two lists:

```
List<double> BulletAngles = new List<double>();
List<OvalShape> Bullets = new List<OvalShape>();
```

My view on how lists work is obviously very off. Right now the bullets are traveling based on this code:

```
foreach (OvalShape b in Bullets)
{
      int i = Bullets.IndexOf(b);
      if (b.Location.X > -10 && b.Location.X < (this.Width - 6) + 10
      && b.Location.Y > -10 && b.Location.Y < (this.Height - 30) + 10)
      {
          b.Left += Convert.ToInt32(bulletSpeed * Math.Cos(BulletAngles[i]));
          b.Top += Convert.ToInt32(bulletSpeed * Math.Sin(BulletAngles[i]));
      }
}
```

The angle is all based on the mouses position when clicking, but when testing this, all bullets go in the direction of the first mouse click.
Here is also the code for setting the angle and placing in the bullet:

```
Point target = new Point(mousePos.X - origin.X, mousePos.Y - origin.Y);
OvalShape g = Bullet;
double y = Math.Atan2(target.Y, target.X);
g.Left = origin.X - (g.Width / 2);
g.Top = origin.Y - (g.Height / 2);
g.Visible = true;
BulletAngles.Add(y);
Bullets.Add(g);
```

Comment: I don't see the error yet, but one comment about your use of lists: don't use two "side by side" lists like that unless you have measured performance and determined that it's *necessary*. Instead, put the `OvalShape` and `double` together in a class so that the list is of self-contained objects. Then you don't have to do that wasteful `IndexOf` check.

Comment: Consider using a dictionary or, as 31eee384 said, combine bullets and angles in a new class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the [IndexOf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4w08k17(v=vs.110).aspx) method might not return the result you are looking for as this method determines equality using the default equality comparer.

While having properties relating to an object in two separate lists is problematic and would be better resolved by encapsulating the properties into a single object as suggested before. If you are trying get the index of an object as you iterate through a list it might be better to use a for statement instead of a foreach statement.

```
for (int index = 0; index < Bullets.Count; index++)
{
    var b = Bullets[index];
    if (b.Location.X > -10 && b.Location.X < (this.Width - 6) + 10
        && b.Location.Y > -10 && b.Location.Y < (this.Height - 30) + 10)
    {

        b.Left += Convert.ToInt32(bulletSpeed*Math.Cos(BulletAngles[index]));
        b.Top += Convert.ToInt32(bulletSpeed * Math.Sin(BulletAngles[index]));
    }
}
```

Here is an example using encapsulation:

```
public class OvalShapeBullet
{
    private readonly OvalShape _ovalShape;
    private Point _location;
    private readonly double _angle;
    private double _distance;

    public OvalShapeBullet(Point orgin, Point target, OvalShape ovalShape)
    {
        _ovalShape = ovalShape;
        _location = new Point(orgin.X - ((int)ovalShape.Width / 2), orgin.Y - ((int)ovalShape.Height / 2));
        _distance = Math.Sqrt((orgin.X - target.X) ^ 2 + (orgin.Y - target.Y) ^ 2);
        _angle = Math.Atan2(target.Y, target.X);
    }

    public Point Location { get { return _location; } }

    public bool Visible
    {
        get { return _ovalShape.Visible; }
        set { _ovalShape.Visible = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Attempts to move bullet to target
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="distance">The distance the bullt will travel</param>
    /// <returns>True if bullet connects with target</returns>
    public bool TryMoveToTarget(float distance)
    {
        if (_distance <= 0)
            return true;        // check if bullet has travelled far enough

        _location.X += (int)(distance * Math.Cos(_angle));
        _location.Y += (int)(distance * Math.Sin(_angle));
        _distance -= distance;

        return _distance <= 0;  // check if bullet has traveled far enough
    }
}
```

Your code then becomes cleaner as the original statements become a single list declaration

```
List<OvalShapeBullet> Bullets = new List<OvalShapeBullet>();
```

Handling of creating a new object

```
        Point target = new Point(mousePos.X - origin.X, mousePos.Y - origin.Y);
        OvalShapeBullet g = new OvalShapeBullet(mousePos, target, Bullet);
        g.Visible = true;
        Bullets.Add(g);
```

and managing the movement of the bullets and checking for target connection

```
        foreach (OvalShapeBullet b in Bullets)
        {
            if (b.TryMoveToTarget(bulletSpeed))
            {
                // handle bullet has hit the target
                Bullets.Remove(b);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this helped lots!